# Centering multiple DIVs inside container of unknown size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I have multiple blue divs of known size (180 x 180 px) inside a container of unknown size.

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

            .content {
                border:1px solid black;
                background-color: grey;
                overflow:hidden;
                text-align:center;
            }

            .block {
                width: 180px;
                height: 180px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color:blue;
                margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <div class="block"></div>              
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <div class="block"></div> 
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <div class="block"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7653/).

I'd like to know two ways of centering these blue boxes.

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just use `inline-block` on your block element.

```
.block {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7656/

Comment: Right answer (for second case) but his result shows 7 `<div>`, http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7656/ same code as you just show the result better as can match the second image layout if extended right.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show me the first way of centering?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I can't add the eddited fiddle. So here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="content">
          <div class="box">
          <div class="block"></div>
          <div class="block"></div>              
          <div class="block"></div>
          <div class="block"></div> 
          <div class="block"></div>
          <div class="block"></div>
          <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.content {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.box {
    width:555px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.block {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this fiddle for the first way:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7656/

I created another div so the blocks are centered. The styling for the blocks is now:

```
.block {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

The styling for the div I added (which class name is "box") is:

```
.box {
    width:555px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I think you accidentally pasted fiddle from Kiee's answer.

Comment: Whoops, I did indeed. Sorry for that.